# Unable to read pdf file in Marathi text in Java program

Tags: java

I am getting this exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/asn1/DEREncodable
>           at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfEncryption.(Unknown Source)
>           at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader.readDecryptedDocObj(Unknown Source)
>           at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader.readDocObj(Unknown Source)
>           at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader.readPdf(Unknown Source)
>           at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader.(Unknown Source)
>           at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader.(Unknown Source

Comment: Don't just share error stack, also share the code you tried when you got this error.

Comment: show us the code you are trying?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're following the `Getting started with iText Guide`. I daresay you will find the [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391271/itext-bouncycastle-classnotfound-org-bouncycastle-asn1-derencodable-and-org-boun) very useful.

Comment: I think this could have been a comment !