# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/asn1/ASN1Encodable

Tags: java, exception, timestamp, itext, bouncycastle

I use iText `5.5.0` and BouncyCastle `bcprov-jdk15on-1.50` for digitally signing a pdf. It all works fine if I do not include a time stamp in the `MakeSignature.signDetached` method.

When I use the `TSAClient` specifying the `TSAURL`, my code gives me the error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/asn1/ASN1Encodable at MakeSignature.signDetached method
```

and my program gets terminated even though I handled exceptions.

I tried different versions of bouncycastle jars but I get the same error with difference in the classes not found.

I really need Timestamp included in the Signature. What should I do.

Comment: What is `jdk15on`, and how are you including the jar? The Maven iText build includes artifacts that have the class you mentioned, and it also appears in all the BC versions I see listed on Central.

Comment: bcprov-jdk15on-1.50.jar is the latest version of BouncyCastle I found on internet. I am using 'add external jars' in eclipse to include the jar in my project. Yes that's true that the class ASN1Encodable is listed in all BC versions but in latest versions it is as an interface not a class. I am not sure that could cause the problem.

Comment: Please first try the version mentioned in the maven dependencies (currently 1.49). Bouncy Castle is known to do fundamental API changes in seemingly minor version changes.

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391271/itext-bouncycastle-classnotfound-org-bouncycastle-asn1-derencodable-and-org-boun ?

Answer (score 6):

You can check the dependency of itext 5.5 at the following URL.

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itextpdf/5.5.0

According to this page, corresponding version of bouncycastle for itext 5.5 is 1.49. I read on a page somewhere on internet that bouncycastle is heavily changing and it is often hard to find corresponding version of bouncycastle for a specific version of itext.

Answer (score 1):

Please download the **bcprov-jdk15on-150.jar** (for JDK 1.5 - 1.7) file from below given link and add in your project to resolve **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/asn1/ASN1Encodable** exception.

http://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html

find the appropriate jar file from the above link according to your JDK version.

Comment: With iText 5.5.x we only recommend to use BouncyCastle 1.49, that is the only version we use. BouncyCastle has been known to not respect Semantic Versioning and make incompatible API changes in minor version changes, as @mkl wrote above. That is why I am downvoting (Disclosure: I am QA Engineer @ iText Software).

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way of including iText in your project, is to use Maven. Maven will then solve the dependencies for you. I read that you use Eclipse, Eclipse has a very good Maven plugin.

Put this in your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
  <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
  <version>5.5.8</version>
</dependency>
```

More info available at http://developers.itextpdf.com/itext-java

Answer (score 0):

remove the folder bouncycastle (org/bouncycastle) from .m2, and run mvn clean compile to download dependencies