# How to check pdf is protected using itext in java

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am using itext library to know whether the pdf file is protected or not.
i am also add boncycastle library to my class path but it still showing error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bouncycastle.asn1.DEREncodable
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 7 more
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391271/itext-bouncycastle-classnotfound-org-bouncycastle-asn1-derencodable-and-org-boun

Answer (score 1):

Put this library in your classpath [bcprov-jdk15on-1.47.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.47/bcprov-jdk15on-1.47.jar)

**UPDATE**

Mind your bouncy castle dependencies version according to the IText version you are using. To double check it with maven repositories. eg. [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.lowagie/itext) or [here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Citext)

Comment: +1; but please inspect the maven pom for the preferred Bouncy Castle version. E.g. version 5.5.0 documents a dependency on BC 1.49.