# Bouncy Castle Error In Itext

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am using Itext Library. I am listing out the embedded fonts from a pdf file. Some pdf files are being parsed correctly but for some pdf flies I am getting this error.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/bouncycastle/asn1/ASN1OctetString

I went through this link

[iText/BouncyCastle ClassNotFound org.bouncycastle.asn1.DEREncodable and org.bouncycastle.tsp.TimeStampTokenInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391271/itext-bouncycastle-classnotfound-org-bouncycastle-asn1-derencodable-and-org-boun?lq=1)

But I am not getting my solution.

My Version of Itext is **5.5.6**
Java - **1.8**

How to install the dependencies of bouncy castle with my version of itext. Can someone give me a layman answer?

**P.S** I am more of a PHP Developer than Java . so I am really confused on solving this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by updating my dependency of bouncy castle.

Updated with **bcprov-jdk15on-1.52.jar**  from the below link of maven repository

**[mvnrepository- bcprov-jdk15on/1.52](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.52)**