# bouncycastle and iText versions

Tags: java, itext, bouncycastle

I am using `iText` 5.5.11 following  [digital-signatures-chapter](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/security/digital-signatures-white-paper/digital-signatures-chapter-2).
I have created my `KeyStore` - ks.jks file and added `bouncycastle` jar to my `classpath`.

Using `bouncycastle` 14-157(latest) version i got -

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bouncycastle.tsp.TimeStampTokenInfo
```

following [TimeStampTokenInfo-class-not-found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391271/itext-bouncycastle-classnotfound-org-bouncycastle-asn1-derencodable-and-org-boun) I tried to use bouncycastle 14-145 and this error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.digest.MD2$Digest
```

Anyone knows what else can I try?

The full error log:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/jcajce/provider/digest/MD2$Digest
    at com.mataf.GenSig.PfxDS.sign(PfxDS.java:51)
    at com.mataf.GenSig.PfxDS.main(PfxDS.java:71)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.digest.MD2$Digest
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 2 more
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A look at the [iText 5.5.11 Maven pom.xml](https://github.com/itext/itextpdf/blob/5.5.11/itext/pom.xml) reveals:

```xml
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
      <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
      <version>1.49</version>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
      <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
      <version>1.49</version>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.8.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.santuario</groupId>
      <artifactId>xmlsec</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.1</version>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Thus, iText is compiled using the Java version 5-8 version of BouncyCastle version 1.49.

Comment: Thank, trying and posting the result.